# How does .NET decide which server to contact for AD information? Or is it all local?

Tags: .net, dns, active-directory

We're having issues with this call:

```
// using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username);
```

where `FindByIdentity` sometimes throws an `LdapException` claiming that the AD is unreachable. We've noticed that `flushdns` (usually) resolves the problem temporary (and when it does not, pinging the local DNS server seems to do the trick).

I'd like to figure out exactly what kind of lookups this call tries to make, in order to narrow down exactly what our problem is.

What network calls does the `FindByIdentity` call make, and where does it look up which servers to contact?

Comment: is this for windows AD or azure?

Comment: From what I understand, it just does a DNS lookup on your domain name and uses the first IP returned (which may be different each time). Do you have a decommissioned domain controller still showing up in DNS?

Comment: @AntonToshik: It's for Windows AD; otherwise I'd have used the [azure-active-directory] tag.

Comment: @GabrielLuci: so, if I log in with FOOBAR\baz, it's just `nslookup foobar`?

Comment: @TomasLycken - Yes, if you perform an authentication with foobar\baz, the code tries to resolve the `foobar` thing with the help of DNS, which in turn will give you any of the domain controller available. If you're facing intermittent connection problem, either you've a not properly demoted Domain Controller, or an incorrect DNS entry, or you may have network connectivity reaching the DC!

Comment: The algorithm explanation by MS: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961830.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It just looks up your domain name via DNS and uses the first IP returned.

DNS returns the IPs of all the domain controllers for the domain, but alternates the order that they're returned. So if you have, say, a decommissioned domain controller still showing up in DNS, then you'll experience failures only when DNS returns that IP first in the list.

Do an `nslookup domain.com` and check all the IPs returned. You can use the telnet client to check them: `telnet [IP] 389` - a blank screen means success, otherwise it'll tell you that it failed.

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems at the moment like there's a broken DNS somewhere, but we don't really know where yet.